# Cannot find module xxx/plugins/octetstream.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, httpserver, formidable

I am building an electron app that hosts an http server. I am using formidable to receive incoming files.

Whenever my app receives a POST request I am seeing the following exception in the stacktrace:

```bash
(node:39275) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/project/.webpack/main/plugins/octetstream.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext (/path/to/project/.webpack/main/index.js:49428:10)
    at /path/to/project/.webpack/main/index.js:47655:83
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new IncomingForm (/path/to/project/.webpack/main/index.js:47652:33)
```

I am new to webpack so I am not sure what kind of rule i need to setup to make this work. Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. This had nothing to do with Webpack.

I ended up updating Formidable (from 2.x.x. to 3.x.x) and electron (from 13.x.x to 21.x.x) and it worked.